# Como fazer um filtro composto com Jpa usando @Query?

Tags: java, query, spring, jpa, filter

Preciso fazer um filtro em uma entidade (AnuncioVaga) composto por atributos que são:

- área de trabalho
- horário de trabalho
- aceita trabalho remoto
- aceita PCD
- tipo de contrato

`aceitaTrabalho` e `aceitaPCD` são variáveis boleanas, e é onde está a minha dificuldade

Sabemos que variáveis boleanas apenas recebem dois possíveis valores, `true` ou `false`, nesse caso, meu anúncio de vaga pode aceitar trabalho remoto ou não, a mesma coisa para saber se aceita PCD, ou aceita, ou não.

Agora, na hora de fazermos o filtro, todas as variáveis de filtro, se não informadas, não serão considerados na consulta, e portanto, virá todos os anúncios, sem restrições.

Recapitulando, se eu não passar valores (filtragem) nessas duas variáveis boleanas, elas nao vão retornar como nulo se nao for informado, pois o valor padrão de boolean é false, e portanto, já se aplica um filtro aqui, mesmo que eu não tenha passado nada.

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM AnuncioVaga a " +
            "WHERE (:#{#filter.areaTrabalho} IS NULL OR a.areaTrabalho = :#{#filter.areaTrabalho}) " +
            "AND (:#{#filter.horarioTrabalho} IS NULL OR a.horarioTrabalho = :#{#filter.horarioTrabalho}) " +
            "AND (a.aceitaTrabalhoRemoto = true OR a.aceitaTrabalhoRemoto = :#{#filter.aceitaTrabalhoRemoto}) " +
            "AND (a.aceitaPCD = true OR a.aceitaPCD = :#{#filter.aceitaPCD}) " +
            "AND (:#{#filter.tipoContrato} IS NULL OR a.tipoContrato = :#{#filter.tipoContrato}) "
    )
    Page<AnuncioVaga> findAllByFilter(AnuncioVagaFilter filter, Pageable pageable);
```

Assim está configurado o meu filtro, vejamos que,

```
"AND (a.aceitaTrabalhoRemoto = true OR a.aceitaTrabalhoRemoto = :#{#filter.aceitaTrabalhoRemoto}) " +
"AND (a.aceitaPCD = true OR a.aceitaPCD = :#{#filter.aceitaPCD}) " +
```

O filtro configurado assim, faz com que, quando nós não passamos parâmetros ele retorna todos os anúncios, pois ele sempre retorna true e, como não passamos nada, o valor padrão é false, então, ele buscará os anúncios como true, pois está na query e retornará os false, pois não passamos nada, e ele retorna false como padrão.
Se nós passamos true como parâmetro da filtragem, ele só me retorna os anúncios que aceitam tal condicao, nao trará nada de false.

Mas agora eu quero filtrar somente pelos que recebem false, completando o filtro:
buscando geral, buscando se for somente true, e buscando se for somente false, eu sei que eu tenho que mexer no "AND (a.aceitaTrabalhoRemoto = true OR..." mas eu não sei como fazer

Answer (score -1):

Se entendi corretamente, sua Entidade possui atributos do tipo `boolean` primitivo que aceitam `true` ou `false`, porém você deseja aplicar um filtro com valores `null`, `true` ou `false`.

Sugiro que você considere uma abordagem diferente. Não acredito que a utilização do `@Query` seja a melhor opção neste caso. Existem outras formas de busca disponíveis, como [Busca Por Exemplo](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example), Busca por Critério, [Busca por Especificações](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) e [Busca por Critério](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria).

Por exemplo, uma Busca por Critério poderia ser implementada da seguinte maneira:

```
@Autowired
private AnuncioVagaRepositorio anuncioVagaRepositorio;
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Test
void quando_CriterioDeBuscaNull_Entao_RetornarTodosOsValores() {
    // AnuncioVaga com construtor (Integer id, boolean aceitaPCD)
    var anuncioTrue = new AnuncioVaga(1, true);
    anuncioVagaRepositorio.save(anuncioTrue);
    var anuncioFalse = new AnuncioVaga(2, false);
    anuncioVagaRepositorio.save(anuncioFalse);

    Boolean criterioDeBusca = null;
    var criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    var query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(AnuncioVaga.class);
    // SELECT FROM AnuncioVaga
    var anuncioVaga = query.from(AnuncioVaga.class);

    // Predicados que serao utilizados clausula WHERE do SQL
    List<Predicate> predicados = new ArrayList<>();

    // Filtrar os valores apenas quando criterioDeBuscas nao for null
    if (criterioDeBusca != null) {
        // WHERE AnuncioVaga.aceitaPCD = :criterioDeBusca
        Predicate aceitaPCD = criteriaBuilder.equal(anuncioVaga.get("aceitaPCD"), criterioDeBusca);
        predicados.add(aceitaPCD);
    }
    // Aqui voce pode acrecentar mais predicados

    List<AnuncioVaga> resultadoDaBusca = entityManager
            .createQuery(query.where(predicados.toArray(new Predicate[0])))
            .getResultList();

    /* 
     * Verificando que retornou todos os valores quando criterioDeBusca eh null
     * Se criterioDeBusca for true, retorna apenas anuncioTrue e virce-versa para false
     */
    assertTrue(resultadoDaBusca.contains(anuncioTrue));
    assertTrue(resultadoDaBusca.contains(anuncioFalse));
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Bot Achei a resposta clara. Favor ser mais especifico com a sua duvida.

Answer (score -3):

De fato está na hora de procurar uma abordagem diferente. @Query não vai te suprir nesse caso sem gambiarrar toda a query.

Sugiro o uso de Specification do CriteriaBuilder. Lá você pode adicionar validações que você quer, exemplo:

> Optional.ofNullable(filtro.tipoContrato).ifPresent(value -> predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("tipoContrato"), value))):

Essa validação vai adicionar o filtro somente se existir valor para o filtro. Se não, será ignorado. Se tiver em dúvidas sobre onde adicionar esta validação, é no @Override do toPredicate().

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esse site é um Q&A técnico. Não use as publicações para interagir socialmente ou tecer networks, para esse tipo de interação temos os chats. Prefira ser objetivo, argumentando de maneira mais técnica focado no que foi perguntado na página.